# Proving these spaces are not surfaces

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Hi all,

Here I have two problems that really I can´t know how solve.

1. For $X = S^2 \cup \{x_0\}$ where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^2$, being $S^2$ the sphere. In $X$ we consider the usual topology for points in $S^2$ and for $x_0$ the open sets are $(U \setminus (0,0,1)) \cup \{x_0\}$, being $U$ a neighborhood of $(0,0,1)$ in $S^2$.
2. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$, where in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we take the usual topology and in $\mathbb{R}$ the discrete topology (everything is clopen).

In both situations (1. and 2.) prove that any point of $X$ has a neighborhood homemorphic to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $X$ is not a surface.

I suppose that in 1. the problem is with the open neighborhood of $x_0$ and in 2. is with the discrete topology. But any hint more detailed? I know that there are so questions, but I´ve not any idea about how you can do it all.

Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: *Surface* in what exact sense?

Comment: Does your definition of surface include *Hausdorff* and *second countable* topological space?

Comment: Homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, compact and connected.

Comment: @user540275, homeomorphic to an open (in the usual topology) subset of $\Bbb R^2$ and compact are mutually incompatible. *Locally* homeomorphic is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing surface means 2-dimensional [topological manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold):

(1) Your "surface" isn't Hausddorff.

(2) Your "surface" isn't second-countable.

Comment: For (2) we even so don´t mention second-countable, so I suppose that the reason is another one. Maybe it is not compact (since it´s not bounded)?

Comment: @user540275, obviously isn't compact (nor $\Bbb R^2$!).